# Postgres COUNT instances and put in "buckets"

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a big table with row that each have a location id (`location_id`). Down the `location_id` column there are multiple instances of the same value. What I want to do is count how many times each value appears and then place that value into a "bucket"

I tried this, but ended up with everything in the "500+" bucket.

```
SELECT
 CASE WHEN count(location_id) > 1 AND count(location_id) <= 25 THEN '1-25'
 WHEN count(location_id) > 25 AND count(location_id) <= 500 THEN '26-500'
 WHEN count(location_id) > 500  THEN '500+'
 ELSE 'nothing'
 end as bucket,
 count(*) as Column1
FROM myTable
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want two levels of aggregation:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN cnt <= 25 THEN '1-25'
             WHEN cnt <= 500 THEN '26-500'
             ELSE '500+'
        END) as bucket, COUNT(*) as numlocations, SUM(cnt) as numTotal
FROM (SELECT location_id, count(*) as cnt
      FROM myTable
      GROUP BY location_id
     ) l
GROUP BY bucket
ORDER BY MIN(cnt);
```

Comment: Thanks! I think this is working perfectly. I end up with 3 columns though and I'm not entirely sure what they mean. The first is `bucket`, which is clear. What are `numlocations` and `numTotal`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
    Select 
     CASE WHEN #_cnt >= 1 AND #_cnt<= 25 THEN '1-25'
     WHEN #_cnt > 25 AND #_cnt <= 500 THEN '26-500'
     WHEN #_cnt > 500  THEN '500+'
     ELSE 'nothing'
     end as bucket,
   count(*) as column1
    from
    (
    Select location_id, count(*) as #_cnt
    from
    myTable
    group by location_id
    ) a
group by bucket
```

Thanks:-)

Comment: This doesn't group by bucket. I should only end up with 3 rows, but that's not what I'm getting.

Comment: fixed it. Check please and let me know if there are still questions around this

Comment: I'm a bit confused about what happened here. In theory, the `nothing` bucket should be empty because everything that's being counted has at least a count of 1. Your counts for the 500+ and 25-500 buckets line up with @gordon's answer, but the other two don't.

Comment: forgot to put >= with 1. It was >1 instead it should have been >=1. 1 was going in to else condition i.e., nothing. Hope it clarifies your doubt.